# Change Label text between fade in and fade out transitions

Tags: javafx, label, transition

I'm trying to change a Label's text in between fadein and fadeout as followed:

```
    Label label = (Label) this.cardsValueGroup.getChildren().get(1);
    label.textProperty().set(String.valueOf(cardsValue));

    SequentialTransition t = new SequentialTransition();

    if (this.cardsValueGroup.getOpacity() == 1.0) {
        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), this.cardsValueGroup);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0.0);
        t.getChildren().add(fadeOut);
    }

    FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), this.cardsValueGroup);
    fadeIn.setFromValue(0.0);
    fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);

    t.getChildren().add(fadeIn);
    t.play();
```

How can I add Label text transition as well?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
fadeOut.setOnFinished(event -> label.setText(...));
```

Or if you're still using JavaFX 2,

```
fadeOut.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText(...);
    }
});
```

(you have to make label final in this case).